# Como obtener un formato de fecha con la anotación @JsonFormat en java spring-boot

Tags: java, json, xml, spring-boot

Como obtener la siguiente estructura `2020-08-18T10:49:43.7397371-04:00` con la anotación `@JsonFormat` en java ***spring-boot***.

Hasta el momento he podido conseguir la primera parte de esta estructura, es decir logro obtener: `2020-08-18T10:49:43` con la anotación `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`

Pero no he podido obtener lo demás, lo que esta va después de la hora, es decir `.7397371-04:00`

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class SemillaModel {

    //private String valor;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date fecha;
}
```

> PD: estoy consumiendo un Api Rest que tiene la siguiente etiqueta XML:
> **`<fecha>2020-08-18T10:49:43.7397371-04:00</fecha>`**

Comment: Y buscaste en la documentación como es el formato de los mili segundos (7397371) y si no me equivoco la parte de (-04:00) es la zona horaria. Aparte del formato `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` que otro has investigado o intentado colocar. Revisa estos enlaces: [java SimpleDateFormat with TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37747467) y [SimpleDateFormat with TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19112357)

Comment: El patrón que buscas es `"yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`. De todas formas, tal como sugiere @OrlandoDeLaRosa, la documentación es el lugar a buscar. Saludos